# Order by selected tables field from other table field, hibernate or simple sql

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate

I have 3 tables. My tables are

```
PRODUCT ( pro_id, name , api )
Definition ( def_id, name )
Product_details ( id, pro_id, def_id, value )
```

pro_id and def_id are foreign keys of tables product and definiton.

My tables record are like this

```
Product ( 1, Goal , A01 ) , ( 2 Shampoo, A01 ) , ( 3, Cell, A02 )
Definition ( 1, Effect ) , ( 2, Satisfaction ) , ( 3, total )
Product_details ( 1, 1, 1, 5 ) , ( 2, 1 , 2, 1 ), ( 3, 1, 3, 3 ) ( 4, 2, 3, 2 )
```

I want to select product where API = "A01" and order by product_details value

Solution should be Goal, Shampoo.

I tried many things but , i couldnot get what i want,

I am using jsf, hibernate, i cant write hibernate query coz i still could not do it with sql, can someone help me fro sql script or hibernate script.

Comment: You have 3 rows with different `value` in `Product_details` table corresponding to `prod_id = 1`. in that case, which `value` should be considered for `order by`.

Comment: the last one coz, 3 mean total in definition table. ( 3, 1, 3, 3)
first field "id" second one "product_id" third one "total" in definition table and last one the value

Comment: to be specific, last one of which order ? is it `max(id)` or `max(value)` or `min(id)` or `min(value)`

Comment: is should be order by max(value) sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :

```
SELECT p.name
FROM   Product p
       JOIN (SELECT pro_id,
                    Max(value) AS value
             FROM   Product_details
             GROUP  BY pro_id) pd
         ON p.pro_id = pd.pro_id
ORDER  BY pd.value
```

Comment: Do you have any opinian how can i implement it with hibernate ?

Comment: Sorry mate, I don't know anything about hibernate, this was for oracle.

Answer (score 0):

```
select pr.pro_id,pr.name,pr.api 
from 
(select pro_id,name,api from product) pr,
(select pro_id,max(value) from product_details
group by pro_id) pd
where pd.pro_id=pr.pro_id;
```